I want to dynamically create QWidgets and dynamically arrange them in a QGridLayout
I'm coding a project management app for my school project. In this app, the user creates a "folder" to organize their different projects. I have implemented this functionality in the "create new project" button. Ideally, when the user creates their first project, the project should appear as a white square in the top left corner of the grid. When the user creates their second project, the next white square should take the position (0,1) and so on. I want only four project folders (white squares) per row. After that, new projects will be added to the second row, and so on. After three rows, the area should become scrollable.
I'm having trouble achieving this behavior. Currently, when I add the first project to position (0,0), the white square appears in the center of the grid. When I add the second white square, the space gets divided between the two squares. This continues until there are four squares in the row. The second row works as expected, but when the third row is created, all the white squares merge together and no scroll bar appears.
This is what happens when I create the first project:

When I add the second project:

After the fourth project has been added everything works as expected until the 9th project is created (first white square in the third row. This is when thew white squares merge.
Third row of projects:

This is how the first project should look like:

This is how all projects should look like:

Below is my code:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QScrollArea, QSpacerItem
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon, QAction
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from ColorWidget import Color #QWidget with a background Color


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # Window Properties
        self.setWindowTitle('project')
        self.setMinimumSize(1050, 650)


    # Main Layout)
        main_pannel = Color('grey')
        main_pannel_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_pannel_layout.setContentsMargins(50,100,50,0)
        main_pannel_layout.setSpacing(20)


    #Main Pannel Sub frames

        # Control 
        control_frame = Color('grey') #QWidget with background color Grey
        control_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        control_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    

        # Project
        project_frame = Color('grey') #QWidget with background color Grey
        self.project_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.project_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 50, 0, 50)
        self.project_layout.setHorizontalSpacing(20)
        self.project_layout.setVerticalSpacing(20)

            #Scroll Area 
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll_area.setWidget(project_frame)
        

        #Control Widgets

        #create new project button
        create_project_button = QPushButton(parent = control_frame, text = 'new project')
        create_project_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        create_project_button.clicked.connect(self.create_project)

        
        control_layout.addWidget(create_project_button)
        
        #set Layout for Control Frame
        control_frame.setLayout(control_layout)
        

        # Project Widgets
        self.project_count = 0
          
        
        #Set layout for Project Framself.
        project_frame.setLayout(self.project_layout)

       
    #Add subframes to Main Pannel 
        main_pannel_layout.addWidget(control_frame)
        main_pannel_layout.addWidget(project_frame,1)
        main_pannel.setLayout(main_pannel_layout)


        
    # Set up main widget
        canvas = QWidget()
        canvas.setLayout(main_pannel_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(canvas)

    def create_project(self):
        row = self.project_count // 4
        col = self.project_count % 4
        new_project = Color('white')
        new_project.setFixedSize(200, 150)  # Set a fixed size for each project widget
        self.project_layout.addWidget(new_project, row, col)
        self.project_count += 1

 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    with open('BunkerWindowStyleSheet.css', 'r') as f:
        app.setStyleSheet(f.read())
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()



Add self.project_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop). Also, you're adding project_frame to the main_pannel_layout, which is the reason for the "merged" boxes: you're never actually using the scroll area. Change to main_pannel_layout.addWidget(scroll_area, 1). Finally, for further reference, always provide proper [mre]s: your code is missing the Color() class, and the style sheet file (if it is essential for the problem, it should be included, otherwise it's irrelevant, and should not be part of the code).
